# Key error while getting header from json load

Tags: python, json, request, header

Here is the piece of code I wrote to output json data from api link

```
import requests
import json
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request('https://servers-frontend.fivem.net/api/servers/single/4lqxao'), headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
sopen = urlopen(req, timeout=10)
data = json.loads(sopen.read())
print(data["clients"])
```

but when I try to print specified header value I get this error (json output prints correctly, but specified header doesn't)

[image]

What is a problem?

Comment: `clients` is not a key in your json. Are you sure it's `'clients'` and not `'Clients'`,`'clients '`  or some other variation?

Comment: when u enter link provided in code you can see that value is: "clients":147

Comment: Sorry, but I am not going to make a request to a random api that I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have a typo in the code you provided, I believe you mean

```
req = Request('https://servers-frontend.fivem.net/api/servers/single/4lqxao', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
```

instead of

```
req = Request('https://servers-frontend.fivem.net/api/servers/single/4lqxao'), headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
```

Secondly, the response comprises of a dictionary of two keys, 'Endpoint' and 'Data' and the 'client' key you are looking for exists in the nested 'Data' dictionary. As a result you can access it through data['Data']['clients']. Verified it myself.

```
print(data['Data']['clients'])
```

> 140